# R function telling me not enough x observations for a two sample T test

Tags: r

I have a csv file and am reading it into R. Then I am trying to call a two sample t test and i keep getting the error Error in t.test.default("v1") : not enough 'x' observations
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

This is my code. I am attempting to try to find v1-v2<0 but I haven't even been able to get this to run doing a normal not equal to 0 test. The data is not pooled.

```
 study <- read.csv("caseStudy.csv")
t.test('V1','V2')
```

Comment: `'V1'`, when you put it in quotes like that is literally the letter V and the number 1 stuck together--nothing more. If there's a column in your `study` data frame named "V1" and you want to give that column to a function like `t.test` you need to use `study$V1`. So try `t.test(study$V1, study$V2)`. Alternatives that should also work are `with(study, t.test(V1, V2))` and `t.test(study[["V1"]], study[["V2"]])`.

Comment: It works thanks! I knew my syntax was wrong somewhere but I couldn't find any resources for the proper way to reference the columns.